# Unable to auth CLI, conf does not reference requirepass

Tags: redis

I am trying to remove Redis sentinels from old Windows servers and the key to doing this points to the Redis CLI. I have been unable to authenticate the cli.

I continuously receive a "NOAUTH Authentication required" response. I have confirm that "Requirepass" in the windows.redis.conf is commented out. Everywhere I look this seems to be the only resolve but nothing works to authenticate even un-commenting the password and try to authenticate via that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s9O1.png)

```
# If the master is password protected (using the "requirepass" configuration
# directive below) it is possible to tell the slave to authenticate before
# starting the replication synchronization process, otherwise the master will
# refuse the slave request.
#
# masterauth <master-password>`

# Require clients to issue AUTH <PASSWORD> before processing any other
# commands.  This might be useful in environments in which you do not trust
# others with access to the host running redis-server.
#
# This should stay commented out for backward compatibility and because most
# people do not need auth (e.g. they run their own servers).
# 
# Warning: since Redis is pretty fast an outside user can try up to
# 150k passwords per second against a good box. This means that you should
# use a very strong password otherwise it will be very easy to break.
#
# requirepass ######
```

I tried un-commenting the requirepass ref but the password will not work. I have also tried with requirepass commented and auth still does not work.

I am working off of one sentinel of nine. I need to remove 5 sentinels.

Comment: If you change the configuration file, the Redis instance need to be restarted to use the new configurations.

Comment: @duckoak I've attempted with no change to result.